# Python Min Max While loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, max, min

Below two while loop codes to find a maximum and a minimum values from a given numbers. the first code is not working, output is wrong, which I dont understand why?

the second one is working, after I decalred the input as an integer; if someone could explain for me, how does this make a difference. Thanks

Code1:

```
 largest = None
 smallest = None

 while True:

     num = input("Enter a number: ")

     if num == "done":
         break

     if largest is None or num> largest:
         largest = num
     elif smallest is None or num< smallest:
         smallest = num

 print ("Maximum is", largest)
 print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Code2

```
 largest = None
 smallest = None
 while True:
     try:
         num = input("Enter the number: ")
         if num == "done":
             break
         num = int(num)
         if largest is None or largest < num:
             largest = num
         elif smallest is None or smallest > num:
             smallest = num
     except:
         print("Invalid input")

 print ("Maximum is", largest)
 print ("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Everything coming from `input` is a string, even if you intend it to be a number value. So anything you want to be treated as an `int` that is brought in with `input` must be converted to an `int`. That's true for both Code1 and Code2.

Comment: Hint: `'3' > '20'` is `True`.

Comment: @Matt Cremeens , for code 1, if i would enter the following sequence of numbers: 10, 2, 8, 4 the output will be Max is 8, Min is 4, whereas for code 2 the output will be correct Max is 10, Min is 2. I would like to understand why the output pf Code 1 is wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output for "code 1" is different from what you expect because the operands in the comparison are `str`, for which the defined order is different from the order of the corresponding `int`.

In other words, if `a` and `b` are two `int`s such that `a > b`, then we can be sure that `str(a) > str(b)` only if the length of the two string is the same, otherwise it can happen either `str(a) > str(b)` or `str(a) < str(b)` depending on the actual value of `a` and `b`.

The ordering of string consisting of numbers is "alphabetical" on characters appearing first, hence, while `"1" < "2" < "3"`, etc., when the two strings have multiple characters, either option is open e.g.:

- for `"2"` and `"10"`, `"2" > "10"` (opposite of `2 < 10`) because `"2" > "1"` and the presence of `"0"` after the `"1"` is irrelevant
- for `"2"` and `"20"`, `"2" < "20"` (same as `2 < 20`) because `"2" == "2"` and the presence of `"0"` after the `"2"` in `"20"` makes `"20"` "bigger".

Note that the string ordering/comparison actually work for any string, even those not containing numbers.